# What type of service is this?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wsdl

Can you please help me in understanding, what type of service is this and what are the possible endpoints for it:

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://your.name.net" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:i0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="RedPill" targetNamespace="http://your.name.net">...</wsdl:definitions>
```

I am trying to build a WCF service by looking at this WSDL. I have a page where I can send my service url and that page runs some testing on my service. When I test my service operation - WhatIsYouToekn using SOAP Client (SOAPUI), I am able to receive response but when I submit my service for Automated testing, my endpoint fails.
 I receive :
"The message with Action 'http://your.name/IRedPill/WhatIsYourToken' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

My WCF URL: http://jaspal.space/RedPill.svc

Please help, why I am getting this response. I am stuck here from 2 days. thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

With the piece of WSDL you provided it's very difficult to guess the info you are asking.

If you just want to know the methods and data types provides by the service, you can use a tool like Enterprise Architect to create a Model Diagram based on your .wsdl file.

Another option is if you want to connect to this service, in that case you can use de [wsdl.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool to create a C# proxy class, with that class you can use Visual Studio to generate a class diagram to understand the service.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I just updated my question having more detail. Please hv a look. thanks

Comment: @jNet You need to look at your Automation testing tool to check the contract it's using to send the request, the error could be a mismatch in the action name (maybe misspelled) or in the contract (maybe there are missing params or the names do not match), also check name casing

Comment: I did but can you please tell me how will you check... so that i can make sure i did the right thing.. thanks